# What's the best way to share user accounts between the application and an engine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-engines

I have a website that has `User` and `Group` models and all is well. The User and Group models are two types of accounts that we have and they are currently used for contact information, authentication and authorization.

Now I'm building out the subscription part of the site so we can start billing users (and groups/organizations) who subscribe to our premium services. I've opted to put this new code in a Rails Engine because I hope to deploy the engine only to an environment on a host that is reachable via our VPN, like so:

```
mount Billing::Engine, :at => '/billing' if Rails.env.admin?
```

I've got three models that I'm working with to manage subscriptions:

```
module Billing
  class PricingPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :subscriptions
  end
end

module Billing
  class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :pricing_plan
    belongs_to :subscriber, :polymorphic => true

    # Used for eager loading
    belongs_to :users,  :foreign_key => 'subscriber_id', :class_name => '::User'
    belongs_to :groups, :foreign_key => 'subscriber_id', :class_name => '::Group'

    has_many   :payments
  end
end

module Billing
  class Payments < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :subscription
  end
end
```

The `Billing::Subscription.subscriber` part is what is currently vexing me. As you can see, I'm currently reaching across the engine boundary to get ahold of the `::User` and `::Group` models that live in my application, but that feels icky.

I thought about creating `Billing::User` and `Billing::Group` AR models so that the engine and application can be completely isolated from one another, but it seems a bit weird to duplicate information between two models that are, for now, in the same database (e.g. first_name, last_name, email, etc.)...plus I'd have to duplicate information between them, which is a recipe for disaster, I'm sure.

I also thought about using some kind of wrapping model to abstract away the actual implementation, something like this:

```
module Billing
  class User < ::User
  end
end
```

But if I recall correctly, I ran into problems with the polymorphic behavior I'm after and/or problems with rspec mocking and stubbing so I abandoned that approach.

I'd appreciate any guidance. I've made numerous trips to Google searching for answers but nothing I've seen so far seems directly applicable.

**UPDATE**

Using Carl Zulauf's suggestion, I came up with the following:

```
# File: app/models/concerns/billing/subscribable.rb

require 'active_support/concern'

module Billing
  module Subscribable
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    included do
      has_one :subscription, {
        :class_name  => '::Billing::Subscription',
        :foreign_key => 'subscriber_id',
        :as          => :subscriber
      }

      base = self
      Billing::Subscription.class_eval do
        belongs_to base.name.tableize.to_sym, {
          :foreign_key => 'subscriber_id',
          :class_name  => base.to_s
        }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Which I then invoke thusly:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Billing::Subscribable

  can_subscribe
end
```

This works...so long as I load `User` *before* I call `Billing::Subscription.eager_load :users`...which seems really dicey. Got any suggestions for me?

**UPDATE #2**

I wound up creating an initializer to handle this. This works, but if there are any better options, I'm all ears.

```
# File: config/initializers/setup_billing.rb

User.class_eval do
  include Billing::Subscribable
end

Group.class_eval do
  include Billing::Subscribable
end
```

Comment: To deal with having to load `User` first you might try putting the unary (`::`) operator before the class name. `:class_name => "::#{base}"`

Comment: That doesn't seem to do help...the code in that module doesn't get executed until `User` or `Group` gets loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to have a module in your engine that would add a class macro to `User` and `Group`.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Billing::ModelHelper
  has_subscription # new macro
end
```

`has_subscription` could then:

- Look up the class name (`User`)
- Add the `has_many`/`has_one`/`belongs_to` association to `User`
- Add the special association to `Billing::Subscription` (`belongs_to :user, ...`)

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to add a relation to another class from within this module? I've got the part down where I add the `has_one :subscription` but I can't figure out how to open Billing::Subscription to add my `belongs_to :users` and `belongs_to :groups`. I tried Googling, but again wasn't able to find anything that looked relevant.